# write a method called averageVowels

Tags: java

I am having trouble with a simple arraylist problem I am getting the wrong output, it seems like the program is counting the number of strings in the arraylist instead of counting the characters that are vowels

```
import java.util.*;

public class AverageVowels {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Tooo");
    list.add("beee");
    list.add("ooor");
    list.add("nooot");
    list.add("Toooo");
    list.add("beeee");

    averageVowels(list);
  }

  public static double averageVowels(ArrayList<String> list) {
    double count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
      if (list.get(i).contains("a")
          || list.get(i).contains("e")
          || list.get(i).contains("i")
          || list.get(i).contains("o")
          || list.get(i).contains("u")) {}

      count++;
    }
    double average = (double) list.size() / count;
    System.out.println(average);
    return average;
  }
}
```

Comment: Even if the loop were correct, it's also not calculating the average correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are testing in your condition whenever you find a word that contains any vowels (and you do nothing if the condition is true, which is another problem).

You are not counting the individual vowels in each word.

You should iterate over the characters of each of the input words in order to count the total number of vowels.

```
for (String word : list) {
    for (int j = 0; j < word.length(); j++) {
        if (word.charAt(j)=='a'||word.charAt(j)=='e'||word.charAt(j)=='i'||word.charAt(j)=='o'||word.charAt(j)=='u') {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Besides that, you got the average calculation backwards. It should be :

```
double average = (double)count/list.size();
```

The total number of vowels divided by the number of words gives you the average number of vowels in a word.

Comment: @PM77-1 Maybe I should have written - "you intended to increase the count..." :). The fact that the count++ was outside the condition seemed less relevant considering the condition itself was wrong.

Comment: Thank you, thats what i needed to preserver, How do you know java can you give me any pointers?

Comment: and i don't know how to use a debugger , thats why I am not so good at for loops and nested for loops (eg i can't make a star pattern for my life) I debug in my head...... how can i learn?